AC Condenser making loud noise on start up
Brand new Carrier AC Condenser.
It makes very loud noise on start, check the video link
Ignore the noise you hear for first 4 seconds of video, that is from other AC units on the roof, my unit starts after 4 seconds with loud noise.
Can anyone tell me what could be the reason? This unit is on the roof of 3 storey building, I can hear this loud noise from the ground floor at night.
Is it normal for brand new AC Condenser to make such loud noise?

not normal .....

Was it professionally installed? If so, get the installer back to take a look - a new system should run super-smoothly for the first season at least.

Something to ask your installer:
With this compressor unit being on the roof of a 3 story building, are the refrigerant lines longer than 80 ft to your indoor unit? If so, this is considered a "long line set" and should have a hard start kit installed [link]
Aftermarket hard start products are about $30 [link], or a few hundred for OEM.

Sounds like a compressor, could have wrong refrigerant but could be lots of things. Needs a pro to come look at it to diagnose. But sooner rather than later there won’t be a noise or cold air….
